# Set tab width according to file

Tags: indentation, tab-characters

I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
set expandtab "Use soft tabs (spaces)
set shiftwidth=2 "Set tab width = 2
set softtabstop=2 "Set tab width = 2
set autoindent "Set indent of previous line
```

Now if I open another file which contains soft tabs of width 4 spaces, how can I make Vim to automatically set my tab also to 4 spaces, depending on the file. Currently, if I'm on a line which is indented 4 spaces and I press `o` in normal mode, the cursor jumps to next line, but only 2 spaces from left.
I also tried using `set smartindent`, but doesn't work.

Comment: My guess is that you should have a look at filetype plugins.

Comment: `% vim: softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4` as last line in that file if it's only one particular file and not a general rule.